# Android studio not building the project gives error on Resources. "R" can not be resolved

Tags: java, android

This error comes on my working project. I thought that this error is create because of I used icon as id in `imageview`, it is not resolving by rebuilding the project. When I create a new project it gives the same error on that project too.

[image]

Following xml is one of them. which not belongs to my project and causing the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright (C) 2015 The Android Open Source Project
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License
  -->

<!-- Layout to be used with only max 3 actions. It has a much larger picture at the left side-->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/status_bar_latest_event_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/test_icon"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

    <include layout="@layout/notification_media_cancel_action"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <include layout="@layout/notification_template_lines_media"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="128dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="128dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/cancel_action"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/cancel_action"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/media_actions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        >
        <!-- media buttons will be added here -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_above="@id/media_actions"
        android:id="@+id/action_divider"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my app level gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.usamaakmal.voicechatapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: share your **`layout.xml`** with question

Comment: change `@id/icon` to `@+id/icon` in xml files

Comment: i cant because this is issue of v11/notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml this file not belongs to my project i think this is default template which is provide by android studio

Comment: @UsamaAkmal post your app level **`build.gradle`** file.

Comment: @Abbas i attached in my post please check it

Comment: @UsamaAkmal any libraries under `/libs` folder?

Comment: @UsamaAkmal I had a similar issue where v-21 files were somehow included it was resolved by removing one of the dependencies.

Comment: the `r` tag is for the R programming language, not the Android resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By **Updating android studio** my issued is solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have modified the xml, just change the top `ImageView` id from `test_icon` to `icon`

For Reference, [view link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/HEAD/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/layout/notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks bro but i updated my android studio, after updating it my project worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

try clean/rebuild project also invalidate caches and restart option.

File->Invalidate caches and Restart

when you include layout the current layout doesn't have that layout's ids in its viewgroup thus it's not finding the ids.

use the exact layout in your layout or wrap it with another parent layout

Comment: did you try the invalidate caches option ?

Comment: share your xml file once.

Comment: @himel i attached it with my question please check that.

Comment: @himel `Invalidate Cache and Restart` didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. you are using resources that your current layout doesn't support. Those resources are only available for Relative Layout. Check your layout again and try to change it to exact layout
2. the id "@id/icon" is not exist.

I think your problem that there is no id such as "@id/icon". Check your ids again and fix it

Comment: but this file is not belong to my project. how can i edit that.

Comment: if that is a library, you can download and use it as a local library. In that case, use can fix those errors in that library but it is really difficult. I recommend you to find another library that has no error and has similar purposes for supporting your project

Comment: before that, i think you should check library's instruction again and sure that you don't miss anything

Answer (score 0):

Try 3 things, it may be help:

1. Invalidate caches and Restart
2. delete and Reimport your R file like : 
   import your_package_name.R;
3. check your layout proper and try to synchronise and rebuild your 
   project.